# SQL Server Execution plan different for different users

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a select query that is executed by a hosted database application (ASP). The same select query is used by two groups that are identical in every way. Both are using the same application and same servers (SQL and Application).

Everything is identical except the end-users login details and the machine they are connecting from.

Regardless of the end-users login details, all queries are executed using the same SQL login. Yet, for some reason, the query consistently runs slower for some users than others.

Comment: You mention different execution plans, but describe no differences in the OP. Did you actually experience different execution plans, or are you assuming they are different due to the delay for one user, but not the other?

Comment: Same network? Same bandwidth? How do you know that the execution plan is different?

Comment: Raj - They are both from the same physical location and share the same network and bandwidth.

Comment: SchmitzIT - I am assuming the execution plans are different because of the latency that some of the end users are experiencing compared to other staff in the same location.

Comment: Latency can often be because of the network.  Are you talking about total time for the results to be fetched, or round trip latency for each packet of data?

Comment: Do the two groups issue the exact same set of parameters for the statement?

Comment: Marlin - The total time to execute the query and return the results

Comment: SchmitzIT - Yes. The select query is contained within a SP and both sets of users are passing the same parameters to the query, so they should both be using the same cached plan.

Comment: Get one user from each group to fire the query with same parameters at the same time and runn a trace on the SQL server to see what exactly is going on. From your description, I am assuming that the same set of users are experiencing poor performance.

Answer (score 0):

I have solved the same issue here: [MS SQL - different execution plan for different schemas?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15766583/ms-sql-different-execution-plan-for-different-schemas/15790876#15790876)

Different options for different sessions on the SQL server cause that stored procedure is compiled with different query plan.

Answer (score 0):

In my case solution was in updating statistics for one of the indexes used in execution plan.

Try execute [`sp_updatestats`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173804.aspx) for whole database or run [`UPDATE STATISTICS table_name index_or_statistics_name`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187348.aspx) if you know/suspect some index to update stats.

Comment: You would not believe, but it is. The same query for two different users uses two different execution plan. I have a maintenance plan which rebuild indexes every two days, but somehow it's not updated statistics for index. It's a pretty big partitioned table. Hope my answer will help someone.