# MS SQL - different execution plan for different schemas?

Tags: sql-server-2008

MS SQL SERVER 2008

- We have one stored procedure with the same parameters.
- We have two accounts with different schemas.

And we have different execution plans for these two accounts.

Normally the execution plan should be the same but in our case it isn't.

What can cause this behavior?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you calling the stored procedure using `dbo.procedure_name` or just `procedure_name`? Does it reference objects using `dbo.table_name` or just `table_name`?

Comment: Hi, I am calling the procedure using dbo. But the users are from different schemas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have finally found out where the issue is:

I have run the some code from different user accounts and these user accounts had different `SET LANGUAGE` option.

good article about it: http://allcomputers.us/windows_server/microsoft-sql-server-2008-r2---query-plan-caching-(part-1)---query-plan-reuse---query-plan-aging.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Comments removes formatting, so I post code to check `SET` options here:

```
SELECT  
    SESSIONPROPERTY('ANSI_PADDING') AS [ANSI_PADDING]
    ,SESSIONPROPERTY('FORCEPLAN') AS [FORCEPLAN]
    ,SESSIONPROPERTY('CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL') AS [CONCAT_NULL_YIELDS_NULL]
    ,SESSIONPROPERTY('ANSI_WARNINGS') AS [ANSI_WARNINGS]
    ,SESSIONPROPERTY('ANSI_NULLS') AS [ANSI_NULLS]
    ,SESSIONPROPERTY('QUOTED_IDENTIFIER') AS [QUOTED_IDENTIFIER]
    ,SESSIONPROPERTY('ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON') AS [ANSI_NULL_DFLT_ON]
    ,SESSIONPROPERTY('ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF') AS [ANSI_NULL_DFLT_OFF]
    ,SESSIONPROPERTY('DATEFORMAT') AS [DATEFORMAT]
    ,SESSIONPROPERTY('LANGUAGE') AS [LANGUAGE]
```